# get product name in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to know how to get specific product name in Odoo. It should be returned by a function. Thank you

please help me with this code
`return request.env['product.product_id'].sudo().search([])`

Comment: tell more about your problem

Comment: Needs more information... Where/how are you calling this in Odoo? What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of names in that line you can do:

```
return [o.name for o in request.env['product.product'].sudo().search([])]
```

If you need only one name you can try the following:

```
return request.env['product.product'].sudo().search([],limit=1).name
```

In case you want a special product, don't forget to set the [search domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-domains).

For better answers give more information about your problem and provide more code. Be more specific please.